# Android: Pause thread/game, show menu, resume game/thread?

Tags: android

im making a game on android. i need to pause the game, show the pause menu (through a new activity or a dialog anyhow) and then resume the game. this is how i am pausing and resuming my thread:

```
public void pause() {
            isRunning = false;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    ourThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            ourThread = null;
        }

public void resume() {
            isRunning = true;
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
        }
```

This works perfectly fine when i go to the home screen and everything but im confused on how to show a menu and operate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a popup menu? You could do something where you showPopup() on pause(). Then, you can click anywhere on the screen to dismiss the popup, or you can probably set the resume in the onMenuItemClick

Does that make sense?

```
public void showPopup() {
    // Anchor popoup with layout to "center" menu
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, layout);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}

@Override
public void onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    dosomething();
            resume();

}
```

Comment: Can you help me start a new activity while the current activity stays paused and resume the current activity when the new one is finished? Thats what i meant about a pause menu like used in most games. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: To be clear, the popup menu can be used while the current activity is activity as the backdrop. Then, once the user clicks on an option, by default the popup will be dismissed and then you can have the activity resumed at the same time. Otherwise, when you call a new activity from the old one, I believe that when you press the "back" button, it will go back to the old activity and call onResume(). See here for more info on the Activity Life Cycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Call pause() when menu button on the device is clicked.

Comment: yeah obviously but how to make a pause menu appear and operate on it while the game is paused in the background?

Comment: When you click on the menu button of android (android devices have hardware menu button, normally @ bottom left corner)

Comment: no no im sorry you misunderstood. what i meant was to create a custom pause menu like used in games when pause() method is called and then implement it. or you can think of it as calling a new activity while keeping the current one as paused in the background

Comment: @MuhammadSaad If you move control to another activity using Intent. Then the current activity (in which game is being played) will get paused and on return from pause activity by pressing back button the game activity will resume after calling onResume() method